# WxWidgets: Troubling Callling wxFrame ConstructorE

Tags: c++, constructor, wxwidgets, linker-errors

Okay, I have run into a really bizarre problem.

I have a wxWidgets program that has two frames, a main one, and a secondary one.

The main one has a button that calls the second one to open.

I had trouble with calling a derived class from the second wxframe's class, so I moved the declaration/implementation of the class to before the class for the main frame.

Now I am getting a compile error.

Here is the header file containing the derived wxFrame classes:

```
/***************************************************************
 * Name:      NUEMain.h
 * Purpose:   Defines Application Frame
 * Author:    Cypher ()
 * Created:   2010-10-02
 * Copyright: Cypher ()
 * License:
 **************************************************************/
#include "System.h"
#ifndef NUEMAIN_H
#define NUEMAIN_H


#include "NUEApp.h"
#include "GUIFrame.h"
#include "System.h"
#include <wx/wx.h>


class NUEAsset : public AssetEd
{
    public:
        NUEAsset(wxFrame *frame){} <-- Error here
        ~NUEAsset(){};

        //Xml object
        XmlO SysX;
    private:
        virtual void OnClose(wxCloseEvent& event);
        virtual void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
        virtual void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);

        //Open File Event
        virtual void OpenFile( wxCommandEvent& event ){
            wxFileDialog* OpenDialog = new wxFileDialog(
            this, _("Choose a file to open"), wxEmptyString, wxEmptyString,_("XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml"),wxFD_OPEN, wxDefaultPosition);

            // Creates a "open file" dialog with 4 file types
            if (OpenDialog->ShowModal() == wxID_OK) // if the user click "Open" instead of "Cancel"
            {
                //Change Statusbar to display path of opened file
                SetStatusText(OpenDialog->GetPath(),0);

                //Set m_SysListBox contents to names from ssys.xml
                SysX.load(OpenDialog->GetPath());
                Asset assetsys;
                //Start adding names to m_SysListbox
                //Pointer to system
                for(int i = 0; i < SysX.Sys.size(); i++){
                    assetsys = SysX.Sys.at(i);
                    //Get name of system as string
                    //Convert name from string to wxString
                    m_SysListBox->AppendString(assetsys.name);
                }
                // MainEditBox->LoadFile(CurrentDocPath); //Opens that file
            }
                //SetTitle(wxString("Edit - ") <<OpenDialog->GetFilename()); // Set the Title to reflect the file open


        // Clean up after ourselves
        OpenDialog->Destroy();


        }
        //Handle clicking on a system
        virtual void sys_click( wxCommandEvent& event ) {
            //Get the index of the selected item
            int ind;
            ind = m_SysListBox->GetSelection();

            wxString tmp_sys_nam;
            wxString tmp_x;
            wxString tmp_y;

            tmp_sys_nam = SysX.Sys.at(ind).name;
            tmp_x << SysX.Sys.at(ind).x_pos;
            tmp_y << SysX.Sys.at(ind).y_pos;

            //Set the asset name listbox
            m_textPNAME->ChangeValue(tmp_sys_nam);

            //Set the X_pos listbox
            m_textRadius->ChangeValue(tmp_x);

            //Set the Y_pos listbox
            m_textStars->ChangeValue(tmp_y);

        }
};


class NUEFrame: public GUIFrame
{
    public:
        NUEFrame(wxFrame *frame);
        ~NUEFrame();

        //Xml object
        XmlO SysX;
    private:
        virtual void OnClose(wxCloseEvent& event);
        virtual void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
        virtual void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);

        //Launch Asset Editor
        virtual void launch_asset_ed( wxCommandEvent& event ) {
            NUEAsset* asset_ed_frame = new NUEAsset(0L);
            asset_ed_frame->SetIcon(wxICON(aaaa)); // To Set App Icon
            asset_ed_frame->Show();

        }

        //Open File Event
    /*    virtual void OpenFile( wxCommandEvent& event ){
            wxFileDialog* OpenDialog = new wxFileDialog(
            this, _("Choose a file to open"), wxEmptyString, wxEmptyString,_("XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml"),wxFD_OPEN, wxDefaultPosition);

            // Creates a "open file" dialog with 4 file types
            if (OpenDialog->ShowModal() == wxID_OK) // if the user click "Open" instead of "Cancel"
            {
                //Change Statusbar to display path of opened file
                SetStatusText(OpenDialog->GetPath(),0);

                //Set m_SysListBox contents to names from ssys.xml
                SysX.load(OpenDialog->GetPath());
                Asset assetsys;
                //Start adding names to m_SysListbox
                //Pointer to system
                for(int i = 0; i < SysX.Sys.size(); i++){
                    assetsys = SysX.Sys.at(i);
                    //Get name of system as string
                    //Convert name from string to wxString
                    m_SysListBox->AppendString(assetsys.name);
                }
                // MainEditBox->LoadFile(CurrentDocPath); //Opens that file
            }
                //SetTitle(wxString("Edit - ") <<OpenDialog->GetFilename()); // Set the Title to reflect the file open


        // Clean up after ourselves
        OpenDialog->Destroy();


        } */
        //Handle clicking on a system
     /*   virtual void sys_click( wxCommandEvent& event ) {
            //Get the index of the selected item
            int ind;
            ind = m_SysListBox->GetSelection();

            wxString tmp_sys_nam;
            wxString tmp_x;
            wxString tmp_y;

            tmp_sys_nam = SysX.Sys.at(ind).name;
            tmp_x << SysX.Sys.at(ind).x_pos;
            tmp_y << SysX.Sys.at(ind).y_pos;

            //Set the asset name listbox
            m_textPNAME->ChangeValue(tmp_sys_nam);

            //Set the X_pos listbox
            m_textRadius->ChangeValue(tmp_x);

            //Set the Y_pos listbox
            m_textStars->ChangeValue(tmp_y);

        }*/
};

#endif // NUEMAIN_H
```

Here is the header from which the classes derive:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// C++ code generated with wxFormBuilder (version Sep  8 2010)
// http://www.wxformbuilder.org/
//
// PLEASE DO "NOT" EDIT THIS FILE!
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#ifndef __GUIFrame__
#define __GUIFrame__

#include <wx/string.h>
#include <wx/button.h>
#include <wx/gdicmn.h>
#include <wx/font.h>
#include <wx/colour.h>
#include <wx/settings.h>
#include <wx/sizer.h>
#include <wx/bitmap.h>
#include <wx/image.h>
#include <wx/icon.h>
#include <wx/menu.h>
#include <wx/frame.h>
#include <wx/stattext.h>
#include <wx/listbox.h>
#include <wx/textctrl.h>
#include <wx/toolbar.h>
#include <wx/statusbr.h>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#define idMenuQuit 1000
#define idMenuAbout 1001

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Class GUIFrame
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class GUIFrame : public wxFrame 
{
 private:

 protected:

  wxButton* m_buttonAsset;
  wxButton* m_buttonShip;


  wxButton* m_buttonTech;
  wxButton* m_buttonOutfit;

  wxMenuBar* m_menubar2;
  wxMenu* m_file;

  // Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
  virtual void OnClose( wxCloseEvent& event ) { event.Skip(); }
  virtual void launch_asset_ed( wxCommandEvent& event ) { event.Skip(); }


 public:

  GUIFrame( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY, const wxString& title = wxT("NUE v0.0.1a"), const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size = wxSize( -1,-1 ), long style = wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wxTAB_TRAVERSAL );
  ~GUIFrame();

};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Class AssetEd
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class AssetEd : public wxFrame 
{
 private:

 protected:
  wxMenuBar* mbar;
  wxMenu* fileMenu;
  wxMenu* helpMenu;
  wxStaticText* m_staticTextSysboxlabel;
  wxListBox* m_SysListBox;
  wxStaticText* m_staticParamslabel;
  wxStaticText* m_staticText4;
  wxTextCtrl* m_textPNAME;
  wxStaticText* m_staticText5;
  wxTextCtrl* m_textRadius;
  wxStaticText* m_staticText6;
  wxTextCtrl* m_textStars;
  wxStaticText* m_staticText61;
  wxTextCtrl* m_textInterference;
  wxStaticText* m_staticText611;
  wxStaticText* m_staticText612;
  wxTextCtrl* m_textPosX;
  wxStaticText* m_staticText6121;
  wxTextCtrl* m_textPosY;
  wxStaticText* m_staticLinksLabel;
  wxListBox* m_SysHyperlinkslist;
  wxToolBar* m_toolBar1;
  wxStatusBar* statusBar;

  // Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
  virtual void OpenFILE( wxCommandEvent& event ) { event.Skip(); }
  virtual void OnQuit( wxCommandEvent& event ) { event.Skip(); }
  virtual void OnAbout( wxCommandEvent& event ) { event.Skip(); }
  virtual void sys_click( wxCommandEvent& event ) { event.Skip(); }


 public:

  AssetEd( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY, const wxString& title = wxEmptyString, const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size = wxSize( 915,500 ), long style = wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wxTAB_TRAVERSAL );
  ~AssetEd();

};

#endif //__GUIFrame__
```

This is the error I am getting:
\
NUEMain.h|23|error: no matching function for call to 'AssetEd::AssetEd()'|

This is an error calling the constructor in the parent class, but I merely copied the way it was done for the original frame, which worked fine.

What is up?

EDIT 1:

Okay, I replaced

```
NUEAsset(wxFrame *frame){}
```

with

```
NUEAsset(wxFrame *frame): AssetEd(frame){}
```

and it now fails in the linking stage with the following error:

```
)]+0x7e)||undefined reference to `vtable for NUEAsset'|
```

I can't make heads or tails of this error.

EDIT 2:

Oh, and I keep getting this warning as well, but I have been ignoring it. Could this be related:

```
||warning: auto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import specified on the command line.|
```

EDIT 3: I think I solved the problem using the information below and some digging.

It turns out that I was defining some events for a frame that no longer had those events.

Changed the defs, and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AssetEd` does not have a default constructor. If you define any constructor of your own, the default constructor will not be implicitly provided.

The problem is that the base object of a derived class needs to be constructed somehow. If you don't call a suitable constructor from the initializer list, the default constructor will be used implicitly.

`NUEAsset` must simply invoke the constructor of the base class with suitable arguments, e.g

```
NUEAsset(wxFrame *frame): Asset(frame) {}
```

Comment: Okay, now its getting a really weird error: )]+0x7e)||undefined reference to `vtable for NUEAsset'|

Comment: It does this sometimes, and I don't know why. It's not even identifying the place in the header file where the problem is. Also, even weirder, is the fact that this is the same way the other frame does it (without calling the default constructor, and it works fine).